# Express route calling parent route again

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express route like,

**in router/blog.js**

```
router.get('/', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
//some code
res.render('blogs');
})
```

...(i)

Then i have another route for adding a blogs like,

```
router.get('/new', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
//some code
res.render('newBlog');
})
```

...(ii)

The problem is, when i am going to `/blogs/new` in my browser, the code from (i) executes also but it doesn't render the `blogs` template.

why is (ii) hitting (i)?

**Update**

This is the middleware:

```
middleware.isLoggedIn = function (req, res, next) {
if (req.session.isLoggedIn) { //this will be true if the user is autenticated
  return next();
 } else {
   req.flash('login','Please Login First!');
   res.redirect('/login');
  }
};
```

**in app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var blog = require('./routes/blog');
app.use('/blogs', blog);
```

Comment: Put your `/blogs/new` route before  `/blogs` route

Comment: @tyb still the same

Comment: Let me get it right. You hit `/blogs/new` on the browser but `/blogs` route is executed right? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: How are you sure that it is indeed hitting the first middleware? Also, what does the middleware "middleware" do?

Comment: middleware checks if the user is logged in and then calles next() or redirects to Login page. BTW i can see the console logs of the first route when i hit the second one. @Vasan

Comment: '/blogs/new' gets executed and at the same time, '/blogs' also gets executed @tyb

Comment: The code in your question doesn't tell anything, you have to provide a working example

Comment: Do you have any requests in your `newBlog` template? Maybe you're making a request to your first route when your newBlog template is rendered.

Comment: @YouneL the program is very big, i can't put down an working example here.

Comment: @tyb no request. I don't know why it's happening. BTW i am using Request in node.js for getting blog data from an API but the new page doesn't use any request. It's just a simple, router.get('/new', render(new)) <not the actual code though

Answer (score 1):

I think your error may be somewhere else in your code and a more complete example may help in spotting that.

This simple example works as intended and only calls the route and the middleware once, hitting the correct one.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/blogs', testMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.json({'route': 'blogs'});
});

app.get('/blogs/new', testMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    res.json({'route': 'blogs-new'});
});

function testMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);
    next();
}

app.listen(3000);
```

Can you provide some more code? Are you 100% sure that the middleware is hit twice (or from the wrong route)?

Comment: Are you using any internal requests in the /blogs/new route to the same application? 
Also: are you just seeing the middleware being accessed twice or are you actually seeing both routes being access (through console.log) if you make one request only?

Comment: i removed the middleware and it's not changing anything.
no matter where i go i.e.- '/blogs/x/y/z', it hits '/blogs' route

Comment: OK, so just to clarify: you have one console.log in your / route and one in your /new route, if you open /new then you will see both console.log statements executed?

And do you use any requests from /new to your internal application to request further data?

Comment: /new route just render the new.ejs template and in console, i see the log of / route. new page have only one request and that is only when the user hits the submit button.

Comment: That should definitely not happen. Just to rule out obvious things: You don't have any script tag, image or similar resource HTML that would try to load /blogs in your /blogs/new template?

Possibly also something that loads an asset through a variable that may be undefined.

To be able to rule that out:
Does the / route request come *before* or *after* the /new request in the log?

Comment: i replaced /new template with simple res.send('New Blog'). Still didn't change a thing. Everything works just fine. /new route loads the new blog page and it's functionality works. BUT, when new blog page loads, the / route start calling for blogs and i see the log. the / route come after the /new

Comment: Since / route comes after /new, it is very likely a resource in your template (since it happens on all the pages, it may be in your layout).

Check the network tab in the developer tools of your browser to see if any resources request /blogs please.

Comment: as i mentioned, even if i don't render any template, it still occurs

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. So to recap: no template, it happens on all routes under /blogs (not for routes above that), the additional request happens after the requested route and you have removed the middleware as well? This applies to simple routes as well (that have pretty much no logic, let's say a simple `res.json({'success': true})`)?

Comment: the code is very complex, i'll have to take some time and try to make it more simple to test your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: @RifatBinReza Are you able to re-create this issue if you hit the /new URL from CURL or a similar tool?